# Action only being carried out for the last element in the list (Python selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

So I have the following code :

```
for _, item in id_list.iterrows():
    location = item['locationId']
    url = f"https://browser.com/user/{location}/"
     driver.get(url) 

 [SOME ACTION]
```

id_list is a CV file that consists of these kind of values:

`locationId 1234 2345 3456`

For example first output should be:
https://browser.com/user/1234/

**What I want to happen: **
Take the value "locationId" to open the correct browser.com page, then carry out [SOME ACTION]

**What happens now **
It iterates through the whole list and only carries out [SOME ACTION] for the last value in the list.

I understand why this happens, but I haven't managed to fix it yet, is anyone perhaps able to give me a hand?

I have been consistently googling and trying things out for a few hours. I'm a bit of a beginner and still learning. My apologies if this is not a good question

Answer (score 0):

Your [SOME ACTION] block needs to be within the for loop like this:

```
for _, item in id_list.iterrows():
    location = item['locationId']
    url = f"https://browser.com/user/{location}/"
    driver.get(url) 

    [SOME ACTION]
```

In your code the loop would execute, and once it had finished your [SOME ACTION] block would be executed just once.

Comment: Oh so that was it, thank you! I totally forgot how important indentation is in python.

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer worked for you, please mark it with a tick as "Accepted" so that others know this question has been answered.